# Connecting domain name to website deployed at cloud

Tags: hosting, cloud, cname-record, domain-name, a-record

I have a domain name lovedmusic.com. I have signed up for jelastic - a cloud web hosting service. Right now I m utilizing my trail period. I have created a environment with app id http://lovedmusic.jelastic.servint.net/.  Successfully deployed web application and able to access it happily.

Now jelastic has an option to point to a custom domain name. It can be done in two ways

1. by changing CNAME.
2. by changing A record.

I have used first option on April 19(yesterday) and as suggested my registrar, I understood that it will take 24 hours to propagate updates. Today in early morning, I am able to access the web app I deployed at lovedmusic[.]com . But all of a sudden the url is not accessible. As suggested my registrar I have used anonymouse[.]org website to browse safely over internet. And my website url  from ananymouse goes like this : http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://lovedmusic.com .

My confusion point is why my domain name is not accessible from browser when I can access it from anoymouse. What am I doing wrong? How changing A record will serve my purpose? Can Someone help me with these please......

I am unable to change A Record with their IP Address in trail version.

Thanks

Comment: The documemtation to do the same is here as follows  http://jelastic.com/docs/custom-domains .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is currently showing a blank page (the same with your anonymouse link). You will need to fix your website code or make sure the server is configured to render sites for this domain.

While I can't reproduce your problem, your issue with the discrepancy is likely due to the TTL of your record. Your DNS host has mentioned it was about 24 hours, so you will need to wait this out (as it's cached), if you've visited your website <24 hours before you made the record change. Other nodes that haven't yet visited the site (such as anonymouse.org), will get a brand new copy of the record and see something different than what you see. This will eventually fix itself once your TTL expires.

On that note, having a record set with a TTL that long is a bad idea in general and you should request something more along the lines of 10-60 minutes.

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks for reply. If you can access this link http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://lovedmusic.com/ (edited with last slash) you can see circles embedded in a pentagon shape. But my website http://lovedmusic.com/ says connection timed out. Are you able to see Hello World when u access the domain name?..

Comment: And can you let me know how are you seeing TTL of DNS Record, I am very new to this. And how to change the TTL limit.. thanks..

Comment: I can confirm I can see the circles and I can also see the same website successfully (with circles) when I go to lovedmusic.com. Your CNAME record is currently set to 28726 seconds and will need to be updated with the company hosting your DNS (dns1.bigrock.in).

Comment: Thanks! Will contact my Registrar Big rock. But Still I am getting connection timed out when I check. Will wait for some time to complete 24 hours  before checking again..